# Convert plot to nparray

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, speech-recognition, spectrogram

I have a numpy array of shape `(74, 743)` which represents a spectrogram of a few seconds of human speech. I can easily convert this into a matplotlib plot using `plt.subplots.matshow`, but I want to know if it's possible to convert the plot into the original numpy array? At the least, how does matplotlib generate an image from an arbitrarily shaped array?

I am trying to create a Generative Adverserial Network that will produce images (this is due to the network's superior performance at image generation) of spectrograms. Then, I want to convert these spectrogram images into the quantitative spectrograms, i.e plot into a numpy array.

Comment: What does "convert plot into original array" mean?

Comment: I should be more specific, I mean the image saved of the plot. So RGB pixels into array that the plot was created from.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to apply a colormap to a 2D array. Using matplotlib tools this could look like

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = np.random.rand(74, 743)

cmap = cm.viridis
norm = Normalize(data.min(), data.max())

output = cmap(norm(data))

print(output.shape)
```

The output is an array of shape `(74, 743, 4)` with values between 0 and 1, denoting RGBA colors.

Comment: I guess you're right. How would you suggest I go from the colour map back to the 2D array?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already have the 2D array available.

Comment: I am trying to create a Generative Adverserial Network. Essentially, it will learn to make colourmaps after being shown heaps of existing colour maps (the ones I've created). But there is no 2D array mapping for the generated colour map, hence, I'd like to try and infer that array from the colour map.

Comment: A colormap is a function. It maps values between 0 and 1 to rgba vectors. If you know the colormap there is no need to learn anything, you already have all the information available. However, given one image with a colormap applied to it, there is no way to infer back the original data it has been created from. But again, that isn't necessary, because you already have the 2D array available.

Comment: I might try just feeding the array itself into the neural network. The network is not mapping the array to a colour map, it’s mapping random noise to a colour map based off of the colour maps I’ve shown it. So for a particular generated colour map from the network, there is no 2D array.

Comment: If you need further help, you need to be more precise with the notions. As said a colormap is a *function* (`f: [0,1] -> [0,1], [0,1], [0,1]`). So I don't understand the above at all.